# Canvas blurry after drawing rotated canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, blurry

I'm trying draw canvas on a new one but not only to draw it, I also need to rotate it. The angle is not divisible by Math.PI / 2 and the new canvas is getting more and more blurry (after each rotation).
When I changed the rotation to be just with angles which are divisible by Math.PI / 2 everything was alright.

Is there any solution to that problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `save` / `rotate` / `restore`

Comment: Could you knock up a JSFiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're drawing an image onto a canvas each time., that image just so happens to be another canvas.

Since it has to approximate pixels because you're rotating, you're losing information each time.

If you *need* this to be exact then you can't do it the way you are. Instead of doing a bunch of stuff on Canvas A and then rotating Canvas B and drawing Canvas A atop, you need to instead:

1. Remember all the drawing commands used on Canvas A Rotate Canvas B
2. (Re)commit those drawing commands on the Canvas B that has had a rotation transformation.
3. Remember in your stack of commands that rotation, so that when you do more things on Canvas B you'll be able to draw those perfectly as well to an eventual Canvas C.